# How to autocollapse/close open menu item

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to autocollapse/close open menu item (dropdown) when clicking another item to open.
Now I need to close open item by clicking that again.

So for example I have opened Item2:
- Item1
- Item2

- Subitem1
- Subitem2

-Item3

When I click Item3 it should autocollapse/close Item2.

Here is the code:

```
else if (Drupal.settings.jquerymenu.hover === 0) {
$('ul.jquerymenu:not(.jquerymenu-processed)', context).addClass('jquerymenu-processed').each(function(){
  $(this).find(selector).click(function(){
    momma = $(this).parent();
    if ($(momma).hasClass('closed')){
      if (Drupal.settings.jquerymenu.animate === 1) {
        $($(this).siblings('ul').children()).hide().fadeIn('3000');
        $(momma).children('ul').slideDown('700');
      }
      $(momma).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
      $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
      return false;
    }
    else{
      if (Drupal.settings.jquerymenu.animate === 1) {          
        $(momma).children('ul').slideUp('700');
        $($(this).siblings('ul').children()).fadeOut('3000');
      }
      $(momma).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
      $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Any demo you can provide?

Comment: @Justcode Yes. Here is working example: http://s9b461090e1ebd7c.s3.simplytest.me/ Menu on the left

Comment: could you possibly consider using a jquery plugin?